# CT class instance with non-literal variables in separate namespace

Tags: c++, constants

I have a simple struct:

```cpp
struct Test
{
    int a;

    Test(int b, int c)
    {
        a = b * c;
    }
};
```

I need to declare CT `TransformData` variable. It works with `#define`:

```cpp
#define testDefault = Test(1, 2)
```

But I need to separate this variable to a separate namespace. If I use `consexpr` I get the error:

> the type «const Test» of «constexpr» variable «test» is not literal

I've googled about constexpr and seems constexpr limits don't allow declare such class instance as constexpr.
Which are there ways to declare such constant?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290747/817643

Comment: By the way, why you want to use `constexpr` and not `static const` data?

Comment: @Phil1970 I'm not sure exactly but I think `static const` is a RT constant. But I need to declare default values. I think the best way is CT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you show is actually a good candidate for producing constexpr constants. But its constructor needs to be marked `constexpr`.

```
struct Test
{
    int a;

    constexpr Test(int b, int c)
       : a(b*c) // must be initialized up to C++20
    {
        a = b * c + 1; // but can still be reassigned
    }
};
```

A ["literal type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) is a normative term for types that can produce constant expressions. Your compiler was telling you that one of the requirements is missing.

Comment: What about more difficult classes? struct Test was just an example. https://pastebin.com/sjAh9sKN. There is a more difficult struct here. A constructor has ~ 115 code lines. Need to describe all lines twice? Declaring a function for constructor? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `constexpr` code has some limitation. You need to start with simple cases to understand when it can be used. At first, I would not expect such large constructor to be a good candidate for `constexpr`.